# How to clear lru_cache across different processes - Python2.7

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, caching, functools

I'm working on a Django project (version 1.11 - Python 2.7) and I need to create a new endpoint to clear all the methods cached using lru_cache decorator.

In this project I have several cached functions like this one:

```py
try:
    from functools import lru_cache
except ImportError:
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache

...

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def my_function():
    pass
```

When the backend starts ten different processes were created using [Twisted library](https://docs.twisted.org/en/stable/).
I'm wondering if it is possible to clear lru caches for each process and how.

I know that it is possible to clear the lru_cache using the `cache_clear()` method and there are [several strategies](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clear-lru-cache-in-python/?ref=lbp) to do it, but I think that it is a mono-thread scenario.

Is it possible to do the same across several processes?

Answer (score 0):

The Python docs for `lru_cache` say "The cache is threadsafe so the wrapped function can be used in multiple threads.": https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

I'm not sure if the `backports.functools_lru_cache` would be any different to the real one from Python 3, though.

Although the idea you link to about using the garbage collector to list the decorator objects is interesting, it seems arduous, and does not constitute "several strategies".

I can't see how you're going to get a list of objects any other way unless you make a list of those objects. I suggest you create your own decorator to wrap `lru_cache` and build a list of the functions in there. Then you can provide your own `cache_clear` function which iterates over that list.